# Validating an input that is dependant of an other

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to make a small form with two numeric input fields, input two will be dependant of input one as follows two = one+/-x

```
<form id="test" class="form-horizontal">
 <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="v1" id="v1"/>
 <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="v2" id="v2"/>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#test').formValidation({
    fields: {
        v1: {
            validators: {
                between: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 50,
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        },
        var temp = document.getElementsByName("v1")[0].value,
        a1 = temp -1,
        a2 = temp +1,
        v2: {
            validators: {
                between: {
                    min: 'a1',
                    max: 'a2',
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by doing this:
Main page

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML =   xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>
<form id="test" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">V1</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="v1" id="v1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"/><p>10 to 50</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">V2</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="v2" id="v2"/><div id="txtHint"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#test').formValidation({

    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        v1: {
            validators: {
                between: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 50,
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        },
        v2: {
            validators: {
                between: {
                    min: 'v2a',
                    max: 'v2b',
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

gethint.php

```
if($_GET['q'] == null || $_GET['q'] == ""){}else{
$min = $_GET['q']-1;
$max = $_GET['q']+1;
echo"<p>".$min." to ".$max."</p>
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"v2a\" id=\"v2a\" value=\"".$min."\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"v2b\" id=\"v2b\" value=\"".$max."\">";
}
```

I'm sure there is probably a better or an easier way, but this does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

your are using string instead of variables values right here

```
validators: {
                between: {
                    min: 'a1',
                    max: 'a2',
                    message: ''
                }
```

it Should like This

```
validators: {
                between: {
                    min: a1,
                    max: a2,
                    message: ''
                }
```

Why it's happen  is explain here

```
   a1 = temp -1,
   a2 = temp +1,

console.log(a1) // show value of a1
console.log('a1') // show a1 in output because it will considered as string
```

Comment: still doesn't work, if i do `validators: { between: { min: 1, max: 'v1', message: ''}}` the form validates. i'm not sure i'm getting v1 value properly